# Two subsets of A that have the same number of elements and the same value of the sum of therir elements

Tags: discrete-mathematics

It is A set of 100 integers between 1 and 1000000. Prove that there are (at least) two subsets of A that have the same number of elements and the same value of the sum of their elements.

I need some help. I don't have idea.

Comment: Well, just stick to subsets of order $50$.  How many are there?  What's the least possible sum?  What's the greatest possible sum?